# Como testar a aplicação no Iphone? Xcode 8 beta

Tags: ios, xcode, app, iphone, apple

Bom dia, estou fazendo uma aplicação no **Xcode 8 beta** não tenho licença para desenvolvedor (U$ 100), como eu faço para testar no meu Iphone ?

Vocês tem algumas dicas para facilitar os meus testes?

Obrigado.

Comment: Cara mais é a mesma coisa no Xcode 8 ?

Comment: Você tentou a solução proposta lá ?